# React: Can't setState in promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I am very confused about this. I am trying to set the `isAuthenticated` state to `true` after verifying a JWT, and it won't work. The console logs are outputting weird things (screenshot below).

I suspect I am messing something up with the `fetch` promise, but I don't know what.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.authenticate()
    }

    authenticate(){
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/authenticated", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                token: localStorage.getItem("token")
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);        // Server returns true
            console.log(this.state);  // isAuthenticated: false
            console.log(this);        // isAuthenticated: true
            if(data.success){
                this.setState({
                    isAuthenticated: true
                }, console.log(this.state))   // isAuthenticated: false
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

The console logs:

[image]

Comment: `console.log(this.state)` is a synchronous function call - you're calling it and passing `undefined` to the second parameter of `setState` - you _meant_ to do `() => console.log(this.state)`.

Comment: This is why I recommend TypeScript :D

Comment: use `console.table` instead  of `console.log` when you are interested in object state in time

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Riiiiight. So the setState does in fact work. Thank you. I should have probably asked how to render the component after the promise resolves, because I can't get the components to use the `isAuthenticated` value.

Comment: @Babevski React will re-render your component after every setState automatically (unless you tell it not to with a shouldComponentUpdate)

Answer (score -2):

React doesn't bind automatically `this` to class methods.

You have two ways to handle this.

on constructor

```
  constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        }
        this.authenticate = this.authenticate.bind(this)
    }
```

or a bit cleaner ES6 way and use arrow functions

```
authenticate = () => {
  [your code]
  this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true }) // example
}
```